# Is it possible to make my Excel cell equal another cell WHEN not IF 2 cells are the same?

Tags: excel, if-statement, formulas, vba

I have 2 Spreadsheets. The first spreadsheet is the master price file, the second sheet is a subset of those same parts.

[Master Price File](http://ccpricefile.com/storage/rotaryWeb.xlsx)
[Subset from Master Price File](http://ccpricefile.com/storage/HeaderPartsWorksheet.xlsx)

The two linked spreadsheets are the two i'm working on. In the second file (subset) I need cell `U2` through `U148` to equal cell `U2` through `U7835` in the master price file but only WHEN `S2` through `S148` in the subset equals `S2` through `S7835` in the master file.

So to sum it up, cell `U2` (in the subset) needs to be populated WHEN `s2` in the subset = any cell in the `S` column from the master file, make `U2` (in the subset) equal to the `U` (whatever row number was matched in the `S` column from the master file).

If that makes sense to anybody, can you tell me if it is possible?

Comment: What you are asking is all possible using the =IF() function and the =VLOOKUP() function. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Comment: I think in this case, when IS if....

Comment: I tried using the VLOOKUP function mixed with the IF function, but I can only choose a specific cell to return. I need it to return the data in column S of the same row that the Vlookup discovered the match.=IF(VLOOKUP(S2,[rotaryWeb.xlsx]Sheet1!$S:$T,1,TRUE),[rotaryWeb.xlsx]Sheet1!$U$2,"") What am I missing?

Comment: Should I combine the VLOOKUP and IF functions with a HLOOKUP?

Comment: Just tried revising my code. I'm not getting the result that I should get. This time i used:  =IF(VLOOKUP(S2,[rotaryWeb.xlsx]Sheet1!$S:$T,1,TRUE),VLOOKUP([rotaryWeb.xlsx]Sheet1!$U$2,[rotaryWeb.xlsx]Sheet1!$U:$V,1,TRUE),"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(S148,[rotaryWeb.xlsx]Sheet1!$S$2:$S$7835,1,FALSE))=FALSE,VLOOKUP(S148,[rotaryWeb.xlsx]Sheet1!$S$1:$U$7835,3,FALSE),"")
```

Your first VLOOKUP only needs column `S` to check that the value exists.

The 2nd need columns `S` and `U` so it can find the SKU value and get the price for the row.

The 3rd parameter for the `result` column need to be 3 in this formula because the price is the 3rd column in the look up fields. You need to use the `ISNA()` function to test for SKUs that were not found and show "", Otherwise it will show "#N/A"